# How do i make passwords that users enter in Java GUI's not show their values as the user types them?

Tags: java, swing, awt

So basically, trying to figure out how to hide values that users enter in the GUI (ie. java swing, awt) for their passwords.  For example ******** as opposed to the standard **password.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `PasswordField` class.

Check out the tutorial:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html